# vim how to replace backslash and &

Tags: vim, replace

I am using vim and I want to replace
`&\\ \hline` to `\\ \hline`
Can somebody teach me how to do this?
`%s/\&\\/\\/gc` didn't work.
this is for latex table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside the search pattern, you don't need to escape `&` (`\&` is a special atom for branches), but `\` needs to be doubled. In the *replacement part*, a `&` would have to be escaped, just like the `\` (yes, this is a bit complex, unfortunately). So, this would work:

```
:%s/&\\\\/\\\\/gc
```

If you want to assert the following `\hline`, too, it's simpler to end the matching with `\ze` (but still assert that the following part is there); this avoids having to duplicate the part that should be kept (or alternatively capture and re-insert it in the replacement):

```
:%s/&\ze\\\\ \\hline//gc
```